# Give numbers for svg path elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following svg file with a defined marker and different paths.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1024" height="629" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <marker id="start" viewBox="0 0 42 42" refX="10" refY="20" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#000"></rect>
      <text x="10" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" class="number"></text>
    </marker>
</defs>

<path d="M110 543 L98 366" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)" />
<path d="M172 544 L139 454 L140 420 L144 357 L146 283" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
<path d="M151 447 L171 403 L174 326 L164 284 L158 279" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
<path d="M234 571 L224 520 L244 465 L256 404 L248 361 L234 307 L236 256" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
<path d="M383 578 L376 465 L361 430 L325 378 L325 311 L348 234" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
<path d="M376 435 L380 356 L365 331 L358 284 L354 240" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
</svg>
```

For each path element I want a marker displayed with enumerate numbers. So 1,2,3 ......

I want to solve it via javascript but I get the message "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

```
var number    = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var polygons  = document.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
      number[i].innerHTML = i;
      console.log(i);
}
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is, that you're using definitions to render the number. That has two implications:

1. Whereever you use this definition, it will print the *same* content, not different ones (like copying the element)
2. The definition itself only exists once

The first point means, you can only change all of the numbers to the *same* value, not to different ones (what, btw., seems to be what you want to do, so you can not do it how you did it now).

The second one is the cause of your error: You try to iterate over multiple numbers, however, your list of nodes (returned from `document.querySelectorAll('.number')`) only contains one element, as the DOM of your page only has one occurence of this class. So, your loop actually runs out of the array bounds, throwing the error you mentioned.

Actually, I don't know any way of solving your problem without needing to duplicate the markers for each element you want to have a different number for. You could do it in Javascript, something like that:

```js
var number    = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var polygons  = document.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
      var node = number[0].parentNode.cloneNode(true);
      document.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0].appendChild(node);
      node.querySelector('.number').innerHTML = i;
      node.id = 'start' + i;
      polygons[i].setAttribute("marker-start", 'url(#' + node.id + ')');
}
```

However, even if that code works, I would probably not use it in production without carefully thinking about the solution. There may be a better one or at least take a look where potentially this code could break.

Comment: Dear Florian, thank you so much for your response. This is exactly the result I wanted. I will test it in production. But anyway with your code I think I am on the right track. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the marker. However you can do something like this:

- for every path you add a text element:
  <text class="number" **x="110" y="543"** ></text>
- the x and y values for the text are taken from the `d` attribute:
  in this case  d="M**110 543** L98 366"

Alternatively you can choose to add those text elements dynamically in a separate group.

```js
var number    = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var polygons  = document.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
      number[i].innerHTML = i;    
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid; width:90vh;}
text{font-family:Verdana;font-size:8px;fill:#fff;text-anchor:middle; dominant-baseline:middle}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="70 230 350 370" >
<defs>
    <marker id="start" viewBox="0 0 42 42" refX="10" refY="10" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="20" height="20"></rect>
    </marker>
</defs>

<path d="M110 543 L98 366" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)" />
<text class="number" x="110" y="543" ></text>
<path d="M172 544 L139 454 L140 420 L144 357 L146 283" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)" />
  <text class="number" x="172" y="544" ></text>
<path d="M151 447 L171 403 L174 326 L164 284 L158 279" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
  <text class="number" x="151" y="447" ></text>
<path d="M234 571 L224 520 L244 465 L256 404 L248 361 L234 307 L236 256" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
  <text class="number" x="234" y="571" ></text>
<path d="M383 578 L376 465 L361 430 L325 378 L325 311 L348 234" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
  <text class="number" x="383" y="578" ></text>
<path d="M376 435 L380 356 L365 331 L358 284 L354 240" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-start="url(#start)"/>
   <text class="number" x="376" y="435" ></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Good answer. But I thought when I read the beginning of the answer that the coordinates of the text will be taken from `path` using JS

Answer (score 0):

solution is to add a marker tag for each polygon

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1024" height="629" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <marker id="start" viewBox="0 0 42 42" refX="10" refY="20" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#000"></rect>
      <text x="10" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" class="number">1</text>
    </marker>
 
    <marker id="start2" viewBox="0 0 42 42" refX="10" refY="20" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#000"></rect>
      <text x="10" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" class="number">2</text>
    </marker>
 
    <marker id="start3" viewBox="0 0 42 42" refX="10" refY="20" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#000"></rect>
      <text x="10" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" class="number">3</text>
    </marker>
 
</defs>

<path d="M110 543 L98 366" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start)" />
<path d="M172 544 L139 454 L140 420 L144 357 L146 283" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start2)"/>
<path d="M151 447 L171 403 L174 326 L164 284 L158 279" stroke="#E42522" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="20,5" fill="none" marker-end="url(#dot)" marker-start="url(#start3)"/>

</svg>
```

Via javascript , you'll have to add in the defs tag a marker node for each polygon dynamically ( inside the for loop ).